# Can a segmentation fault in a shared library cause another process using that library to segfault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, glibc

This morning I was encountering a strange permissions issue with a users home directory. I am running CentOS 6.9.  This resulted in things like `ls -` and `su user` failing. Within the same second, during one of these segmentation faults, another process (`slurmctld`) segfaulted in the same library.  Here is the relevant blurp from `/var/log/messages`.

```
Aug 11 09:47:10 qmaster01 kernel: slurmctld[31279]: segfault at 0 ip 00002b5a3708f221 sp
00007ffd8414ada8 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[2b5a3700e000+18b000]
.
.
.
Aug 11 09:47:37 qmaster01 kernel: su[1199]: segfault at 0 ip 00002afddd310221 sp 00007ffc3fecd308 error 4 in libc-2.12.so[2afddd28f000+18b000]
```

Now I can't do a full analysis of this issue because the system failed to create a core dump for the `slurmctld` process.  There was a second instance of 'correlated' segmentation faults similar to the one above, except with `su` and `slurmdbd` being the 'correlated' executables.

I am unfamiliar with `glibc` and don't build shared libraries, but it got me wondering.

**QUESTION** :

Is it possible for a process using a shared library that generates a segmentation fault, to cause segmentation faults in other processes using the same library?  If so, under what conditions or provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for a process using a shared library that generates a segmentation fault, to cause segmentation faults in other processes using the same library?

No.

What is *likely* happening is that:

- you have faulty memory and
- that faulty memory happened to be where some frequently used GLIBC routine is loaded. The memory page belonging to executable code in a shared library is shared by all processes using that library (that's what "shared" in shared library stands for!).

You should likely run `memtest86` on the machine for a few hours.

P.S. The crashes happened at offset `0x81221` into GLIBC in both cases (`0x2b5a3708f221 - 0x2b5a3700e000` and `0x2afddd310221 - 0x2afddd28f000`), so the same instruction was likely corrupted.

P.P.S. If you are not using ECC memory, it's possible that the memory is fine, and corruption was caused by a random bit flip (e.g. due to cosmic radiation).